# Including CSS/JS assets from template folder

Tags: templating

I cannot seem to include my CSS and JS files from the `craft/templates/` directory into my website.

I've looked at this answer - [Serving CSS files from template folder](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/serving-css-files-from-template-folder#) - and it tells me I simply need to have a `styles/styles.css` folder and I use `{% includeCssFile "/styles/styles.css" %}` and it should work. But it doesn't. I have a similar problem with the javascript includes. `{% includeJsFile "js/lodash.min.js" %}` command works, but once I navigate to any other URL, it tries to include the file `http://localhost/craft/news/2016/js/lodash.min.js`.

My folder structure looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to keep all my assets in this `craft/templates/` folder because I created a git repo in the craft main folder.

Comment: Not an answer, but just wanted to point out that serving CSS/JS from the templates folder is considered a bad practice – [Brandon outlines why in his answer to the thread you linked](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/3093/1098).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code worked for me - This may be down to using MAMP and having a [config file](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings) that handles my siteUrl and assetsUrl.

There are a few questions already on Stack Exchange that relate to [your folder structure](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15310/creating-partials-outside-of-the-templates-folder/) and how to [include assets in different templates](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15663/loading-javascript-on-specific-sections-pages).